# Click On Image To Open New Tab In HTML Page

Tags: php, post

Click On Image To Open New Tab In HTML Page
how can i add clickable image to open new tab in html page?

Comment: This has been answered many, many, many times before...  Please show what you Googled before asking this question and why it didn't help you.

Comment: can i have any links i searched many times but i didn't find correct ans any where so please give a link which i add code in single.php file in my wordpress. thanks

Comment: What did you find when you searched "open link in new tab in html"?

Comment: here is example link http://www.modafinilsale.com/nature-wallpapers-widescreen.html open this link to click any image then going to open single page i want to add like this in my site. thanks again

Comment: Yep cool, that isn't what I asked you though.  Read my last comment and reply to that.

Comment: many time i searched so please chek my code in single.php file <?php echo get_theme_option('footer_title');  $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');$width=$large_image_url[1];$height=$large_image_url[2];?>
    <a href="<?php echo $large_image_url[0];?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" target="_blank"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full',array('class'=>'shadow')); ?></a> how can i add here link to open in other page?

Comment: Cool.  Yep.  So what have you tried already to achieve that?  I think you're misunderstanding what StackOverflow is for.  It isn't a code writing service.  I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52397802/edit) to include the code you've tried.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

try this one

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open multiple windows.</p>

<a href onclick="myFunction()">  <img src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML tutorial" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a></a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com/");
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok Dear Thanks.

Comment: welcome glad to help

Comment: Please don't answer questions that show no research effort or are direct duplicates of existing questions on the site.  Instead refer the asker to the existing question.  Read the [help].

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark noted but this guy needs help

Comment: Yep he sure does!  He'd be able to get that same help if you just refer him to the duplicate question.  The benefit of this is that the site doesn't get bogged down with duplicate and unhelpful questions/answers like this one.

Comment: Additionally, your solution has unnecessary JavaScript involvement.  The best way to do this is with the `target` attribute: `target="_blank"`.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark i am just tying to help. this guy is somewhat beginner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180310/discussion-between-jeffrey-acenas-and-luke-joshua-park).